# How do I navigate to a specific step of a Wizard control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, aspwizard

I have a `Wizard` control in an ASP.NET page. I am trying to provide links back to the individual `WizardStep`s. I can't find any information about doing it.

Here is some code to help visualize my problem

```
<asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="Wizard">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<%=LinkToTheFirstStep %>">Step 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="<%=LinkToTheSecondStep %>">Step 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <WizardSteps>
        <WizardSteps runat="server" ID="WizardStepPersonal">
        </WizardSteps>
        <WizardSteps runat="server" ID="WizardStepTravel">
        </WizardSteps>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```

Comment: You could also use [this tweak](http://techbrij.com/798/stylish-asp-net-wizard-control-horizontal-sidebar-on-top) to create a navigation if you don't want to use the `SideBar` that comes with the `Wizard`control.

Comment: That is actually what I used in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You could just have a query string variable, like ?step=1 and check against that on page load, then set your wizard like:

```
Wizard.ActiveStepIndex = int.Parse(Request["step"]);
```

Of course with a little more error checking.

Edit: Sorry, the ActiveStepIndex accepts and int and I initially was trying to cast a string to to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `asp:Menu`

**The page**

```
<asp:Menu ID="MyWizardMenu" Orientation="Horizontal" OnMenuItemClick="MyWizardMenu_MenuItemClick" runat="server">
    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="One" Selected="true" Value="0"></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Two" Value="1" ></asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem Text="Three" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>

<asp:Wizard ID="MyWizard" runat="server" OnNextButtonClick="MyWizard_NextButtonClick"  OnPreviousButtonClick="MyWizard_PreviousButtonClick" DisplaySideBar="false">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="one" Title="One" runat="server">One</asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="two" Title="Two" runat="server">Two</asp:WizardStep>
        <asp:WizardStep ID="three" Title="Three" runat="server">Three</asp:WizardStep>
    </WizardSteps>
</asp:Wizard>
```

**The code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MyWizard.ActiveStepIndex = 0;
    }
}

protected void MyWizardMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Int32.Parse(e.Item.Value);
    MyWizard.ActiveStepIndex = index;
}

protected void MyWizard_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MyWizardMenu.Items[e.NextStepIndex].Selected = true;
}

protected void MyWizard_PreviousButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
   MyWizardMenu.Items[e.CurrentStepIndex - 1].Selected = true;
}
```

It should even be possible to bind `MyWizard.WizardSteps` to `MyWizardMenu.DataSource` (to avoid hardcoding your steps to navigation items) but I didn't get that to work yet because simply casting to IHierachicalEnumaration is not enough.